# How to use a SmartTV as second screen over wifi?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-14.04, smart-tv

If we would like to use a SmartTV as a second screen over wifi using Linux, how could we do it? Is there a way to do this?

For my case I'm using a Samsung SmartTV and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with KDE 4.

The TV automatically become a second screen if with we put an HDMI cable to it. And it is capable of sceen mirror too. But I don't know how to use it as a second screen over wifi.

If isn't a way using just the TV, are there devices that we can use to do this?

Comment: Some ideas mentioned here might be worth a try: http://realmike.org/blog/2015/05/27/wip-mirror-your-linux-desktop-to-your-tv/

Comment: If this is about DLNA streaming over Wifi, I wonder if one could make a Wayland backend that just encodes and streams its framebuffer. Sounds like an interesting project ...

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of a software project within the FOSS community to do this. There are plenty of commercial solutions available, you may perhaps Google `linux HDMI over wifi`, you will run into them.

Apart from this search, by the look of it, I especially liked an object called WIFI2HD2 HDMI® over Wi-Fi Adapter by StarTech.com because it does not have a transmitter on the pc, just a receiver attached to the TV. But I am not sure this works with Linux.

There are however other solutions: have you heard of CuboxTV? Nowadays, it comes pre-installed with Xmbc/Kodi, it is a full-fledged Linux pc (which means it can access your Samba shares, NAS, UPnP devices), you can ssh into it, it can be controlled with a smartphone app at no extra cost.

Comment: In fact this is interesting. I'll need to search more about it and return. Looks like we will have on the market a Intel Compute Stick but with Ubuntu. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the miraclecast project, it seems to do something similar to what you are looking for: https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast

I've not tried it out yet though.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably look into Chromecast. Or check if your smarTV has any apps for desktop remote control (RDP or VNC). Some people report the join.me app working ok on LG smart tvs.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with chromecast. Download Chromecast extension to chrome. Go to google Chrome-->click on cast. Then it shows cast tab popup listing TV available for casting. click on sources and select Desktop. Tap on TV option for casting then it will ask you to choose an application to cast. You can choose any application open on the desktop.  So this way you can have one app on a laptop and another app displayed on TV screen.

Hope that helps. Thanks.